# How to get content inside tag in beautiful Shop 4?

Tags: beautifulsoup

how to get all content inside a html tags ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = "<a><b>scgvggvd</b></a>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
matched_list = soup.find('a')
print(matched_list)
```

code above will return :

```
<a><b>scgvggvd</b></a>
```

what i want is :

```
<b>scgvggvd</b>
```

the tag `<a>` is removed after it's found

i hope the solution will works with find_all() too

Comment: use [contents](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) ie: `matched_list.contents`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `<b>` tag is a sibling of the `<a>` tag use the following line:

```
matched_list = soup.select_one('b')
```

If the `<b>` tag is a child of the `<a>` tag use the following line:

```
matched_list = soup.select_one('a b')
```

Use `select` instead of `select_one` if you need multiple hits.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = "<a><b>scgvggvd</b></a>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
matched_list = soup.find('a')
for b in matched_list:
    print(b)
```